# Sub-Select on MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I don't know if this is possible but I'm trying to make a select queries with a couple of JOINS with a WHERE statement. What I need is a field based on a particular WHERE and another field with different WHERE.

Current SQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(a.totaltime), b.user_name, MONTHNAME(a.date)
FROM a 
JOIN c on c.id = a.id                                                                    
JOIN b on b.userid = c.userid    
LEFT JOIN d on a.projid = d.projectid                                                                       
LEFT JOIN e on a.account_id = e.salesorderid                                                          
LEFT JOIN f on e.salesorderid = f.salesorderid                                                      
LEFT JOIN g on d.projectid = g.projectid                                                                     
WHERE c.deleted != "1" AND YEAR(DATE(NOW())) AND ( f.cf_991 = '1' OR g.cf_990 = '1') 
group by user_name,MONTHNAME(a.date);
```

This works fine but I need to include another field this time WHERE would be:

```
WHERE c.deleted != "1" AND YEAR(DATE(NOW())) AND ( f.cf_991 = '0' OR g.cf_990 = '0')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks

EDIT:

CURRENT OUTPUT IS:

```
 total_time        username        MONTHNAME(a.date)
 22.5              admin           April
 21                admin           June
 15                max             April
```

So the above is based on f.cf_991 = '1' OR g.cf_990 = '1'

What I need is this:

```
 total_time        username        MONTHNAME(a.date)        total_time_2  
 22.5              admin           April                    5
 21                admin           June                     9
 15                max             April                    13
```

total_time_2 is based on f.cf_991 = '0' OR g.cf_990 = '0'.

Comment: "I need to include another field this time WHERE would be" what do you mean?

Comment: i.e. instead of issuing another query with a different where I need another column based on another WHERE

Comment: `AND YEAR(DATE(NOW()))` - what does this do?

Comment: can you provide little bit more information on database and sample output you want

Comment: @codeomnitrix please look at edit

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius means to get only dates with current year. i.e. if we're in 2013 it will only get 2013 rows :)

Comment: Well, YEAR function returns YEAR as a number, not YEAR as boolean (!?). This part of query won't affect the query itself at all. On the other hand, if you wrote... `YEAR(somedatecolumn) = YEAR(DATE(NOW()))`, then it would make some sense.

Comment: yes well that's not the point ! I need it to get only the values with the current year and I forgot to right the needed date in the row... but anyway that's not the point..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN f.cf_991 = '1' OR g.cf_990 = '1' THEN a.totaltime END) as total_time
, b.user_name, MONTHNAME(a.date)
, SUM(CASE WHEN f.cf_991 = '0' OR g.cf_990 = '0' THEN a.totaltime END) as total_time_2
FROM a 
JOIN c on c.id = a.id                                                                    
JOIN b on b.userid = c.userid    
LEFT JOIN d on a.projid = d.projectid                                                                       
LEFT JOIN e on a.account_id = e.salesorderid                                                          
LEFT JOIN f on e.salesorderid = f.salesorderid                                                      
LEFT JOIN g on d.projectid = g.projectid                                                                     
WHERE c.deleted != "1" 
AND YEAR(CURDATE()) = a_column_containing_a_date
AND (
       ( f.cf_991 = '1' OR g.cf_990 = '1') 
     OR
       ( f.cf_991 = '0' OR g.cf_990 = '0')
    )
group by user_name,MONTHNAME(a.date);
```

Comment: There's an extra bracket on YEAR((CURDATE()) should be YEAR(CURDATE()) but it's awesome it works !! :D thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
SELECT 
SUM(if(f.cf_991 = '1' || g.cf_990 = '1',a.totaltime,0)),
SUM(if(f.cf_991 = '0' || g.cf_990 = '0',a.totaltime,0)),
b.user_name, MONTHNAME(a.date) FROM a 
JOIN c on c.id = a.id 
JOIN b on b.userid = c.userid
LEFT JOIN d on a.projid = d.projectid 
LEFT JOIN e on a.account_id = e.salesorderid
LEFT JOIN f on e.salesorderid = f.salesorderid
LEFT JOIN g on d.projectid = g.projectid
 WHERE c.deleted != "1" AND YEAR(DATE(NOW()))
and (( f.cf_991 = '1' OR g.cf_990 = '1')  or( f.cf_991 = '0' OR g.cf_990 = '0') )
group by ser_name,MONTHNAME(a.date);
```